# How do I convert a requested JSON message to usable data?

Tags: javascript, json, flask, fetch

I have a flask server running that provides me with a JSON message when I manually visit `127.0.0.1:5000/data/get_data`.
CORS is disabled in this flask server and in my fetch-request I added `{mode: 'no-cors'}` as well.
Whenever I use the fetch-request in javascript, the response is empty while Flask tells me the GET request was heard and a response was sent.
Flask gives me the exact same output when I manually request the data (and I can view the received JSON in the browser).

This is the javascript code to do the fetch-request

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/get_data', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
.then(response => console.log(response));
```

FLASK clearly gets the request and sends a response:
[this image is the INFO message from FLASK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDWT0.png)

[this image is the HTTP response from FLASK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAL2.png)

[what the FETCH-request receives (logged in firefox dev-console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIwS.png)

I would love to know how I can receive the data that flask sends out, and keep it in a dictionary in javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending JSON response in Flask "POST" Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461923/sending-json-response-in-flask-post-route)

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/get_data', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```